# External hard drives keep getting unmounted

Tags: pi-4, power-supply, hard-drive

I have an **OpenMediaVault NAS** on top of the **Raspberry Pi OS Lite** set up on my Raspberry Pi 4B.

I have two 1 TB [Toshiba](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079D359S6) HDTB410XK3AA hard drives connected to the Pi through a powered USB hub.

Now I am experiencing that either of the two drives keeps getting unmounted intermittently. I am using [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00TPMEOYM) hub to power the two USB hard drives.

On the back of the drives it says that the power rating is +5V DC 1.0 A, while the Amazon page linked above says that

`For a stable connection, the devices connected to the 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub must not exceed a combined current of 5 volts 900 mAh`.

Could lack of enough current be the reason for the issue? In the reviews I see people saying that they are able to successfully connect their hard drives to this hub. Which logs should I look for to further investigate the issue?

Comment: You are exceeding the power supply limit.  Power consumption on the drives will vary depending on their use.  I have tried many USB hubs and most fail with 2.5" USB drives.  Constant power on/off cycles will damage your drives.

Comment: @RohitGupta In that case, will getting a new hub with higher output current and voltage help?

Comment: Yes. It will.or split the power cable to 5v supply.

Comment: @RohitGupta Did you mean 'switch' instead of 'split'? I don't fully understand that comment. Also, could you please makes some recommendations for USB powered hub?

Comment: I dont know what cables you have used.  If these are USB drives, then some drives have a split cable at one end, one for data and another for power